Where is Uttara Kuru?
Uttara Kuru is a fabled land that ancient Aryans used to speak of a lot. Whatever good things they encounter they used to say that you can find it in Uttara Kuru. It is kind of a la la land, heaven on earth. They were very much fond of that place, and never missed an occasion to praise the place.
For example, in Ramayana 3.73

Ascending those trees or lowering them by force on earth, do thou proceed living on those fruits like unto ambrosia. Passing by this forest, O Kākuthstha, thou shalt reach another abounding in trees blooming with flowers like unto the garden of celestials and Uttarkuru where in all the months of the year the trees produce fruits and honey and where all the seasons dwell as in the forest of Chaitkraratha.

in Mahabharata, 13.54

And the monarch also heard the harmonious cackle of the geese sporting in the lakes. Beholding such exceedingly wonderful sights, the king began to reflect inwardly, saying, 'Is this a dream? Or is all this due to an aberration of my mind? Or, is it all real? O, I have, without casting off my earthly tenement, attained to the beatitude of heaven! This land is either the sacred country of the Uttara-Kurus, or the abode, called Amaravati, of the chief of the celestials!

I can go on. The place was mentioned many times. The question is this. Where exactly this place is? Is it an imaginary perfect place? or is it their ancient homeland (that is why it is so dear to them)?
